# Showing that X such that $X^TQX=Q$ is orthogonal transformation with respect to the $\langle u,v \rangle = (Qu,v)$ scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am given the following scalar product : $\langle u,v \rangle  = (Qu,v)$ where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the usual scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider a matrix $X$ such that $X^TQX = Q$. Is this matrix $X$ orthogonal with respect to the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$? I think I have to show that $\langle Xu,Xv \rangle=\langle u,v \rangle$. But starting from the left side $\langle Xu,Xv \rangle=(QXu,Xv)$. I am not sure how to continue (note that maybe I have to add some additional assumptions that the matrix is orthogonal or something)

Comment: You wrote that incorrectly, you should instead have
$$
\langle Xu, Xv \rangle = (QXu, Xv)
$$

Comment: okay I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any matrix $A$ and vectors $x,y,$ we have $(x,Ay) = (A^Tx,y)$.

Comment: Thank you. So I have $\langle Xu, Xv\rangle = (QXu,Xv) = (u,(QX)^TXv)=(u,X^TQ^TXv) = (u,(X^TQX)^Tv)=(u,Q^Tv)=(Qu,v)=\langle u,v \rangle$